# Make whole usercontrol clickable using InputBindings in wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

In my UserControl i have drawn some paths inside canvas

In order to open a control panel for this UserControl I used InputBindings like this :

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding OpenControlPanelCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

This is working only when I click on the paths that I have drawn. Actually I want all the UserControl's surface be clickable not only the drawn part

I set the background of the usercontrol but it doesn't working

How can I change this behavior ?

Comment: What happens if you set the canvas background to transparent or a colour?

Comment: I put my paths inside a Canvas and set the background colour but still having click only on the drawn parts of the usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<UserControl …
         Background="Transparent"
         >
    <UserControl.InputBindings>
       <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding OpenControlPanelCommand}"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
    <Canvas>
        <Path Data="M0,0L25.194,16 0,32z" Stretch="Fill"
              Height="100"
              Width="100"
              Fill="Black"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I have it in a window:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1/>
</Grid>
```

Relevant part of vm:

```
using …
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
namespace wpf_99
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    public ICommand OpenControlPanelCommand { get; set; } = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello World"));
```

Is your usercontrol filling the area you're expecting it to?

Is your command binding correctly?

Anything on top of it that's grabbing the click?

Comment: - Actually my usercontrol is not filling the area when i set for example `Background = SomeColor`,  i'm always getting a transparent control even when i set other colors 
- My command is binding correctly (getting expected behavior).

Comment: @Amibluesky: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question. If the UserControl is not filling the area, then this is your issue.

Comment: Put the usercontrol inside a grid or other control that will make it expand to fit whatever area you need it to fill. Or. Set height and width on it's parent usercontrol to whatever size you require.